# What's wrong with my scope, ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where(“(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ? ) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)”, sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
```

I keep getting an error that says:

```
warning: invalid character syntax; use ?\s
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can try replacing this `"”"` and this `"”"` with this `"""`.

Comment: It seemed to work with single quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using angled double quotation marks (`“` and `”`) which is not a valid string delimiter for literals in Ruby. Usually this happens if you are are copying text into an editor not meant for programming like MS Word. Valid delimeters are `'` and `"`.

You can also improve the readability greatly by using named instead of ordinal placeholders.

```
scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
  where(
    "(conversations.sender_id = :s AND conversations.recipient_id = :r ) OR (conversations.sender_id = :r AND conversations.recipient_id = :s)", 
    s: sender_id, r: recipient_id
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation marks are not the standard ones but some weird utf8 characters, use " or ' instead. The error message ist pretty misleading. Some editors are using this format which is not valid for rails.

Comment: I often get caught up with this when copying some data from my password manager.
Your syntax highlighter should be showing that the string's are 'overflowing' the UTF8 characters.